# How to present UIVideoEditorController

Tags: ios, swift

I have never used UIVideoEditorController so I am not sure where to start with it.

I want the view controller to pop up when the user selects a video in my collection view cell.

I already know the URL of the video, so I just need someone to show me how to properly present the view controller.

This is my code so far

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let video = videosArray[indexPath.row]
```

The video variable is the video i want to allow them to edit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let video = videosArray[indexPath.row] // videosArray is a list of URL instances
    if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: video.path) {
        let editController = UIVideoEditorController()
        editController.videoPath = video.path
        editController.delegate = self
        present(editController, animated:true)
    }
}
```

Also you need to add `UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate` methods for dismissing presented video editor controller:

```
extension YourViewController: UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate {
    func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, 
       didSaveEditedVideoToPath editedVideoPath: String) {
       dismiss(animated:true)
    }

    func videoEditorControllerDidCancel(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController) {
       dismiss(animated:true)
    }

    func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, 
               didFailWithError error: Error) {
       print("an error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       dismiss(animated:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to try on real device if you couldn't get it to open because `UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo` returns false.